# real memory increase when remove a custom view which contains few subviews IOS(ARC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory

I have an iPad app which is crashing on iPad (First model) as it is running out of memory.

I create a custom view called RoadSectionView which means one road, and another custom view called CrossRoadView which contains four RoadSectionViews.

RoadSectionView.h:

```
#import "GestureView.h"

@interface RoadSectionView : GestureView <NSCopying,NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startPoint;       //手指触摸起始点
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint endPoint;         //手指触摸终止点

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *startPointView;     //起始控制点
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *endPointView;       //终止控制点

@property (nonatomic)NSString *type;               //路段的类型
@property (nonatomic)NSString *roadName;           //路段名称

@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger roadWidth;            //路道宽，默认为350
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger roadIslandWidth;      //中间路岛宽，默认为40
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger upOrLeftLaneNum;      //上或左路段的路道数，默认为2
@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger downOrRightLaneNum;   //下或右路段的路道数，默认为2

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *startUpOrLeft;              //上或左起始点数组
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *startDownOrRight;           //下或右起始点数组
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *endUpOrLeft;                //上或左终止点数组
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *endDownOrRight;             //下或右终止点数组

- (void)drawView:(CGPoint)point1 :(CGPoint)point2;
- (void)addControlPoint:(CGPoint) start : (CGPoint) end;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame : (NSString *)name;

@end
```

here is the CrossRoadView.h

```
#import "GestureView.h"
#import "RoadSectionView.h"

@interface CrossRoadView : GestureView<NSCopying,NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *type;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint centerPoint;

@property (nonatomic, strong)RoadSectionView *leftRoad;
@property (nonatomic, strong)RoadSectionView *rightRoad;
@property (nonatomic, strong)RoadSectionView *upRoad;
@property (nonatomic, strong)RoadSectionView *downRoad;

- (void)drawView:(CGPoint)start;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame : (NSString *)name;
- (void)addControlPoint;
- (void)addDistanceLine;
- (void)drawConnectLines;

@end
```

the GestureView.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GestureView : UIImageView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,  UIPopoverControllerDelegate,NSCoding,NSCopying>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *parentView;

@property  BOOL isPanEnable;
@property  BOOL isRotateEnable;
@property  BOOL isPinchEnable;

@property BOOL doesHaveTreelawn;

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint imagePoint;       //记录添加的view的在父视图中的起点
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat imageSize;        //记录放缩的倍数
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat imageRotation;    //记录旋转的角度
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint imageTranslate;   //记录平移的大小

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint upContrlPoint;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint downContrlPoint;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

- (void)setGesture:(UIView *)parent : (BOOL)isPan : (BOOL)isPinch : (BOOL)isRotate;
```

@end

when I add few of RoadSectionView in rootView, and than remove them, it works fine, the real memory didn't increased.
the remove code is

```
[self.canvasView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

but when I add few of CrossRoadView in rootView, than I remove them, the real memory increased, as I save them to disk, the canvasView will first remove all subViews when open the file, than I open the file several times, the app crashed

can you help me!! Thanks very much

Comment: Could you please share your CrossRoadView.h file. Thank you

Comment: What is parentView for in GestureView?

Comment: self.superView, it do nothing

Comment: thanks, here is the problem! I shouldn't set it to `strong`, it comes into being a retain cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to use `strong` property for the `RoadSectionView` since they will be retained by the superview (`CrossRoadView`) when you will add them as subview.
Then, they will be release when the superview is destroyed.

Try to use

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) RoadSectionView *leftRoad
...
```

Comment: I change it to `weak` property, but when I create the leftRoad,`_leftRoad = [[RoadSectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame :@"直绘路段"];`, it sad assigned retained object to weak variable, and it the leftRoad can't draw

Comment: Could you explain how work your view hierarchy please ?

Comment: the four RoadSectionRoad first draw respectively, then add to CrossRoadView, in CrossRoadView draw their connection, the GestureView is a UIImageView which add several gesture

Comment: Could you please add the GestureView.h file ?

Comment: And `RoadSectionView.h`
 :p ?

Comment: Ok Then, maybe my answer should be applicated to both of the `UIImageView` properties in `RoadSectionView` or is there another reason to have them strong ?

Comment: I set the properties to `weak`, then how can I create it? it don't work when use `[[object alloc] init...]`